# Validate receipts iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Look like apple is making any type of update this month.... recently my app was rejected with this message

> When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able
>   to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s
>   test environment. The recommended approach is for your production
>   server to always validate receipts against the production App Store
>   first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used
>   in production," you should validate against the test environment
>   instead.

My app was approved before ... this is the code that i m using

```
  //Sandbox URL
       //let url = URL(string: "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")!
        let url = URL(string: "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = bodyData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(.other(error)))
        } else if let responseData = responseData {
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            //print(json)
            let session = Session(receiptData: data, parsedReceipt: json)
            self.sessions[session.id] = session
            let result = (sessionId: session.id, currentSubscription: session.currentSubscription)
            completion(.success(result))
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: It might have been rejected because you're doing the validation on your app, not on a server like Apple suggests.

Comment: but why i need a server? a version was approved 1 week ago without a server

Comment: Maybe they didn't test in-app purchases last time? Your IAP verification will fail because you only verify against the production end-point, but during review you need to verify against the sandbox.  If you don't use a server then there is much less value in verifying the receipt.

Comment: Different reviewers might notice different things, and some times you app won't be reviewed by a person one time and will be once you submit an update. If you don't want to use a server, you could skip the validation...

Comment: And How can i skip validation? if i never had this problem? (I sent you a email Emilio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a server. You can validate it on the client if you want. Or you could completely forgo any validation if you wanted (not recommended).

The rejection you are getting is most likely because this time around, they used a test env to validate IAP.

Their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2387/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014795-CH1-BEST_PRACTICES-ALWAYS_VERIFY_YOUR_RECEIPT_WITH_THE_PRODUCTION_URL_FIRST) states

> If you are doing receipt validation, be sure to verify your receipt
>   with the production URL (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt)
>   first. This applies even in the case where your app is used in the
>   sandbox environment. App Review will review the production version of
>   your app in the sandbox. When your app processes the receipt, it must
>   be capable of detecting the 21007 receipt status code and sending the
>   receipt to the sandbox receipt validation server
>   (https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt). Once your app is
>   approved and running in the production environment, sending the
>   receipt to the production server first is the correct action.

Notice that they don't specify where the receipt validation is done.

What your code lacks is the fallback to the sandbox. Hence why they rejected you this time around.

Comment: So what change must i do in my code? sorry but i m not sure about what must i do

Comment: The instructions are fairly clear about it in the Apple documentation. You already have the JSON from the response. Check the receipt status code. If it is 21007, make another call using the sandbox. If that fails, then it is an true failure.